# Opening WPF Window from another Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am have two different WPF applications running differently. now my requirement is to merge these application. Now Both application are WPF application. So I need to call Second application from the First Application So bascially I have created Two windows and I am initializing the Window2 from Window1 on a button click. Now the problem assuming that I have used the same resource files for both application.

What will happen if I close my First WPF application will the Second application will also get closed?

What should be the best approach in these situations?

If my main application window closes then the resource will also go out of scope and how should i ensure my appliction works correctly?

Comment: Did you try what happens? That will answer all your questions, and you can start looking at what issues you have to fix instead of what issues may arise.

Comment: thanks but already in the middle of mergin the two applications I need to invest some time in that. So I was wondering if anyone has done it

Comment: I am still a little confused. You have 2 separate applications. Now you want to merge them into a single application. Let's say application A has WindowA and application B has WindowB, and that the new application is is application C. Now C loads WindowA, and with a button click in WindowA, you create WindowB (which is from application B). Is that what you're trying to ask?

Comment: I have just have two applications App A and App B currently both are working independentely. But some of my users want AppB to be a part of AAP A. So I thought that I will include App B part of App A. Now I am just looking what should be the best appraoch because both the Application has same set of resources for theming and styling so rather than keeping redundant resources I thought of making it into a single resource dictionary. So the problem is what will happen if the app A is closed will it effect App B

Comment: It is not about how much similarities they have **now**. It is about how they could probably evolve later. If these two are meant to be very similar, such that if they wanted to change A, B would also be changed, then merging this way is correct. If they are expected to follow different evolution paths, then they should stay separated.

Comment: As for implementation, if you want them separate, you can just use `System.Diagnostic.Process` to spawn the AppB's process.

Answer (score 0):

At the Application level you can set the [ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property to define the condition that will make the application terminate.

If the second application cannot run without the first one for some reason, as you suggest in your post, you could set this property to `OnMainWindowClose`. This way, if the first one is closed, the full application will stop

Comment: I am just wondering what should be the best approach? Should the second one is to be closed or should i open it different from the main.

Answer (score 0):

Spawn a new process on button click, that opens AppB. But that will keep both apps separate from each other, so no data sharing either. If you want to share data and code, add each page from AppB manually to AppA just like adding a third party control.